# Simple test class - trigger not fired

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Feels like a DOH moment, but:
I have an org which I need to deactivate all it's triggers, and remove old apex classes. Tedious, but while trying a simple trigger, it's not firing from a test class:

I am just putting some mock code in the trigger.

Trigger:

```
trigger countLeadStatusDuration on Lead (after insert)
{
        // Just to pass coverage
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name = 'test account';
        acc.Account_Type__c = 'SMB';
        insert acc;
}
```

The test class is just as simple:

```
@isTest
public class TestInsertSupportFeesItem {

    static testmethod void testinsertlead(){
        Lead l = new Lead();
        l.Company = 'Test_Lead';
        l.LastName = 'TestLead';
        l.LeadSource = 'Web';
        l.Status = 'New';
        l.Lead_Class__c = 'Grade A';
        l.Top_software_Account__c = 'Top 20';
        l.Email = 'Testnone@gmail.com';
        insert l;
        
        l.Email = 'newemail@stam.com';
        update l;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting 0 coverage from the insert of the lead.

Comment: Perhaps that trigger on Lead has already been disabled/deactivated. Also, the `testmethod` keyword is deprecated and you should be using the `@isTest` annotation instead.

Comment: as I said: DOH moment. Yes, all the triggers were deactivated in the sandbox, before time. DOH.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. I can't recall the last time I experienced one of those (and I'm not all that eager to try to recall one) outside of it was something I was staring at for 8 hours and the issue was a single extra whitespace somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a plain 'ol trigger like that (with no trigger framework being used), I think the only ways that it could fail to execute would be:

1. The trigger has already been deactivated in the org you're working in
2. There is something that causes the test to fail before you perform the DML that would cause the trigger to run

In the second case, you'd expect to get some decent error message as a result of running the test. So if do don't see that, it's very likely that the trigger itself is deactivated.